# Update records in Parse with Geopoints

Tags: parse-platform

I have about 600,000 records I uploaded through the data uploader in CSV format. My longitude and latitude columns are separate. I'm trying to modify the class in cloud code with this script. It updates sometimes and then other times there is an error. Can someone help me with this script or is there a way to do this that I'm not aware of.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("CreatePoints", function(request, status) {

    // Set up to modify user data
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var recordsUpdated = 0;

    // Query for all objects with GeoPoint location null
    var query = new Parse.Query("Class");
    query.doesNotExist("location");
    query.each(function(object) {
        var location = {
            latitude: object.get("latitude"),
            longitude: object.get("longitude")
        };
        if (!location.latitude || !location.longitude) {
            return Parse.Promise.error("There was an error.");
        }

        recordsUpdated += 1;
        if (recordsUpdated % 100 === 0) {
            // Set the job's progress status
            status.message(recordsUpdated + " records updated.");
        }

        // Update to GeoPoint
        object.set("location", new Parse.GeoPoint(location));
        return object.save();
    }).then(function() {
        // Set the job's success status
        status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        console.log(error);
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong!");
    })
});
```

Comment: Mind sharing the error information with us?

Comment: Thanks for the edit...In the parse job status tab its showing that the job is failing. Points 06/28/14 09:00 PM UTC 06/28/14 09:02 PM UTC Failed 
Script Error: 'Uh oh, something went wrong!'

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something small in the script because it runs at first and it'll update alot of records then it'll time out. Then i'll try and run it again and it just doesn't run. It immediately gives me an error.

Comment: Examine the logs to see the real error, either via the admin dashboard (Cloud Code, Logs) or from the command line. My guess is you hit a record where `latitude` and/or `longitude` are empty.

Comment: That's exactly it. Do you know how to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, your issue is that some of the Class members have no `longitude` or `latitude`.

You could change your query to only process those that have both values:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Class");
query.doesNotExist("location");
query.exists("longitude");
query.exists("latitude");
query.each(function(object) {
    // etc
```

Then you no longer need to check for them being empty, no longer need to return a `Parse.Promise.error()`, so should no longer hit your error.

Comment: 1 last question with this. Not all of my records are updating. It's successful but there are still missing locations that's not copying over. I did something and was able to see an error saying "Invalid format for latitude" in the above query I think i need to convert a string to a float. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Use the parseFloat function, e.g. `var lat = parseFloat(object.get("latitude"));`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm having to manually combine these 2 fields because parse is saying it's completing but it's not. I still have tons of location points that's not combining the longitude and latitude..It could be a problem with cloud code